# Rails - Can't create a record that has an attribute with the same name of the class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having troubles trying to create (or even update) a database record, because both the parent class name and the name of an attribute are equal. I'm using a consolidated database, so I can't alter the tables.

I have a class Period with an attribute 'period'. One period has many tax scales.

```
#period model
has_many :tax_scales, 
    foreign_key: 'period', 
    primary_key: 'period'

#tax_scale model
belongs_to :period, 
    foreign_key: :period,
    primary_key: :period
```

So, when I use this in my tax_scale view:

```
#new.html.haml
= f.label :period
= f.number_field :period
```

I get this error:

> Period(#97477176) expected, got String(#8598408)

My controller params are:

```
params.require(:tax_scale).permit(:minimum, :maximum, ..., :period)
```

How can I edit (or create) a tax_scale record succesfully?

Comment: There is only one way, you need to change the attribute name.

Comment: Even if possible why make it I nessecarily confusing?

Comment: The database is used by other people and systems. I can't change the schema

Comment: Is the error only occuring in the view with the form helper?  If so I'd recommend adding a virtual attribute in the model that grabs the period's value via "attr_accessor".

Comment: Thank you @bkunzi01 for your suggestion, it was a good starting point. I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: use methods using self[:attribute], to be sure the attribute is accessed

```
#tax_scale model
def current_period
  self[:period]
end

def current_period=(p)
  self[:period] = p
end

#new.html.haml
= f.label :current_period
= f.number_field :current_period
```

Notice I have to use self[:period] and not self.period, because the second one is still accessing the parent record, not the attribute.